# BaseDaoImpl has an invisible method

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Hi i am following this [tutorial](http://www.b-fil.com/blog/2011/01/20/android-repository-ormlite-existing-sqlite-db/) about ORMLite, 
but when I get to this line of code :

> userDao = BaseDaoImpl.createDao(getConnectionSource(), User.class);

I get the folloing error :

> The method createDao(ConnectionSource, Class) from the type
>   BaseDaoImpl is not visible

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the more up-to-date docs since that tutorial is a little bit out of date.

> http://ormlite.com/docs/dao-setup

You no longer call `BaseDaoImpl.createDao(...)` directly.  Instead use

```
userDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), User.class);
```

Please ping the tutorial owner to have him change his docs.